# How to convert mercurial repository to git repository without losing branches?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree, hg-git

I want to convert mercurial repo to git repo. Actually I did but I didnt see branches. After I converted repo I can see just one branch(as master) I cannot see any other branches but I can see history(all changes) as right. when clicked any commits I can see like this information :

```
Date: 19 Nisan 2019 Cuma 15:14:37
Committer: sevgi.cakmak
Change dialog header

--HG--
branch : sevgi-2.0.0
```

but I cannot see sevgi-2.0.0 branch on the left side (I am using sourcetree).

My steps:

mercurial.ini file:

```
[extensions]
strip = 
histedit = 
rebase = 
hggit = C:\Users\sevgi.cakmak\Desktop\hg-git\hggit
hgext.bookmarks =

[git]
intree = True
```

`hg bookmark -r 2.0.0 master` (also tried like this: `hg bookmark -r default master`) 
and then I worked this line from cmd

```
hg gexport --debug //this line converting all revision
```

after worked this line my output like this:

```
converting revision a318482e0769e2fceb13a1545cb477d60a00b434
converting revision e444655d161131f9ed1676f6c175813097fd18g8
converting revision 0ab06d22eaf4ff4ecb96caba343fdcc3a85e367k
converting revision 8a4e7f4defb0b04e76e67a825bedf746fe4f3fc5  ......etc
```

and then I worked this line `git config --bool core.bare false` . 
After all I did open branches folder under the .git and this older is empty. I want to see branches on my repo.

reference: https://helgeklein.com/blog/2015/06/converting-mercurial-repositories-to-git-on-windows/

also I tried fast-export but didnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [docs section **Usage**](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/src/default/):

> Hg-Git pushes your bookmarks up to the Git server as branches and will
>   pull Git branches down and set them up as bookmarks.

...

> **Configuration**
>
> ...
>
> ```
> git.branch_bookmark_suffix
> ```
>
> hg-git does not convert between Mercurial named branches and git
>   branches as the two are conceptually different; instead, it uses
>   Mercurial bookmarks to represent the concept of a git branch.
>   Therefore, when translating an hg repo over to git, you typically need
>   to create bookmarks to mirror all the named branches that you'd like
>   to see transferred over to git. The major caveat with this is that you
>   can't use the same name for your bookmark as that of the named branch,
>   and furthermore there's no feasible way to rename a branch in
>   Mercurial.
>
> For the use case where one would like to transfer an hg repo over to
>   git, and maintain the same named branches as are present on the hg
>   side, the `branch_bookmark_suffix` might be all that's needed. This
>   presents a string "suffix" that will be recognized on each bookmark
>   name, and stripped off as the bookmark is translated to a git branch:
>
> ```
> [git]
> branch_bookmark_suffix=_bookmark
> ```
>
> Above, if an hg repo had a named branch called
>   `release_6_maintenance`, you could then link it to a bookmark called
>   `release_6_maintenance_bookmark`. hg-git will then strip off the
>   `_bookmark` suffix from this bookmark name, and create a git branch
>   called `release_6_maintenance`. When pulling back from git to hg, the
>   `_bookmark` suffix is then applied back, if and only if an hg named
>   branch of that name exists. E.g., when changes to the
>   `release_6_maintenance` branch are checked into git, these will be
>   placed into the `release_6_maintenance_bookmark` bookmark on hg. But
>   if a new branch called `release_7_maintenance` were pulled over to hg,
>   and there was not a `release_7_maintenance` named branch already, the
>   bookmark will be named `release_7_maintenance` with no usage of the
>   suffix.
>
> The `branch_bookmark_suffix` option is, like the authors option,
>   intended for migrating legacy hg named branches. Going forward, an hg
>   repo that is to be linked with a git repo should only use bookmarks
>   for named branching.

Comment: @eagle glad it helped.

Comment: @eagle @DavelnCaz Can you please share the versions of hg and hggit that you used and where this solution worked? I'm using `branch_bookmark_suffix` but still my open branches get lost during push (transform) to git

Comment: @Jan sorry but I don't recall, it was a couple of years ago I used it last. However, it did appear to work.

Comment: @DaveInCaz No problem. I ended up using the github import feature - that can handle all (incl. unmerged) branches during the import from mercurial

Comment: So, then, I need to create a bookmark in mercurial for each one of my branches?